# SwaggerUI. JsonIgnore removes attribute from schema

Tags: .net, swagger-ui

I have a model (class MyResponse) that has an optional field that shouldn't be serialized when it has a null value:

```
public class MyResponse
{
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public string MyField { get; set; }

    ... // some other properties without jsonignore
}
```

Field is serialized properly (serialized when not null and not serialzied when null). The only problem it is not present is .json schema anywhere! Property MyField is not present inside required nor properties attributes

```
"MyResponse": {
        "required": [
          ... 
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          ...
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      }
```

How can I make MyField present inside json schema?t